# Firebird multiple statements

Tags: sql, database, firebird, statements

is there any way to execute multiple statements (none of which will have to return anything) on Firebird? Like importing a SQL file and executing it.

I've been looking for a while and couldn't find anything for this.

Comment: Could you please post the query you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the normal query-delimiter work? Like:

```
Update stuff; Delete stuff; Update stuff;
```

Comment: It doesn't. So if I have let's say 2 alter statements to execute firebird complains about "Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, column 1.
alter."

Comment: Bobby is right, quey-delimiter is the normal separator. Only two comments: If you are using a tool like FeniSql you must execute the "execute script" command instead of "execute sql statement". 
Also, for procedures you must use the funny syntax "Set Term ^; .... Set Term ;^" and use ^ as delimiter inside the procedure.

Comment: I am using IBExpert, guess I haven't found yet where execute script is. I executed the  same SQL file with FenixSQL and it worked. Bunch of thanks

Comment: I upvoted this answer since it bought me much time and am really curious who downvoted it for which reason.

Comment: Its probably downvoted because its not useful. Trying to run an EXECUTE BLOCK with multiple statements only produces -104 errors and complaints about tokens.  I'm not using any of those query tools - just the Firebird.Embedded and Firebird.Client nuget packages. Setting the terminator should make no difference, but it doesnt work either way.

Comment: I appreciate that this is several years later, however, why is this the accepted answer? Surely it should be the one given by TPAKTOPA?

Answer (score 13):

Execute block is **exactly** for that purpose. Works in **IBExpert** too, a simple example :

```sql
execute block as
begin
  Update stuff; 
  Delete stuff; 
  Update stuff;
end
```

Comprehensive guide, with temporary variables and cycles into it:
[`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml-execblock.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from IBExpert with Script Executive (Menú Tools -> Script Executive). Be sure to connect to the DB you want to run the query's and then at the Script Executive dialog check the "Use current connection" for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

In IBExpert you can execute multiple commands in single script via Tools->Script Executive (Ctrl+F12)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with IBOConsole (download from www.mengoni.it). The SQL window allows you to enter a complete script with the usual ";" delimiter.